# Reset Chosen Select to Original Disabled State

Tags: angularjs, jquery-chosen

I have two chosen select elements, one bound by the other. Before the first selection is made, the second element is shown in its default disabled state because its assuming the first model hasn't been activated. I have a "clear filters" button that is supposed to reset these elements back to this state...

So far, what I'm using to reset the chosen elements is the following...

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <label>Vehicle Make</label>
    <select id="carMake" ng-model="carMake" chosen ng-options="carMake as carMake.name for carMake in carMakes track by carMake.name">
         <option value="">All</option>
     </select>
 </div>

 <div class="input-group carModels">
     <label>Vehicle Model</label>
     <select id="carModel" ng-model="carModel" chosen ng-options="carModel as carModel.name for carModel in carMake.models track by carModel.name">
           <option value="">All</option>
     </select>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
$('#clear-filters').on('click', function() {
    $('form').each(function() { this.reset() });
    $('select').val('').trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```

So far, the JS is successful in resetting my chosen elements to the "All" selection. However, it doesn't seem to REALLY be updating the model value and the second element doesn't go back to its disabled state.

Does this make any sense? Hoping it does and that someone can provide some insight. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the chosen directive code?

Comment: I'm using localytics/angular-chosen directive... I've updated the code above.